# How to parse HTML into a paragraph in iText7

Tags: html, parsing, itext7, xmlworker

In iText5 is was possible to parse HTML code into a phrase using xmlWorker. Now i have to switch from iText5 to iText7 and there is no xmlWorker any more.

Is it possible to parse HTML code (using a string) into a paragraph in iText7. Possibly using pdfHTML? An example would be nice. i am not an iText professional.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71335178/convert-html-tagged-text-to-string-for-a-pdf-itext7

Comment: Also you can find some examples here: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-to-pdf